# How to connect to mysql running on docker using Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelpro

I have a docker-machine up and it has a mysql container running.

```
~
▶ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103
~                                                                                                                                                                       
▶ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100

~
▶ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.9.1

~
▶ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
b14062dd1e25        mysql:5.6           "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   6 hours ago         Up 6 hours          3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3306->9090/tcp   i-mysql
```

logs from `docker logs i-mysql`

```
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.28 started; log sequence number 1625997
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@b14062dd1e25' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2016-01-20 04:14:41 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

How can I connect to the mysql instance in this container from my localhost laptop running OSX using Sequel Pro.

I'm using the below settings but I can't seem to connect:

[image]

> Unable to connect to host 192.168.99.100, or the request timed out.
>
> Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary
>   privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10
>   seconds).
>
> MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.99.100' (61)

Answer (score 1):

You are exposing container port 9090 to host port 3306. Maybe you wanted the other way around. When you start the container **please change -p flag parameter from 9090:3306 to 3306:9090**

Answer (score 0):

Have you added permissions to the root user for requests coming from the host ip?